# How to set the key name on an array in Angularfire

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am creating arrays using Angularfire but I am unable to set the key name. Firebase is automatically giving me a cryptic key (eg Jm9vLy8Lye-KS35KsmL) but I would like to set it myself to something more meaningful. It is unclear how I do this in Angularfire. I am using the $add method on $firebaseArray:

```
var firebaseRef = new Firebase("https://firebase_location"); 
$scope.messages = $firebaseArray(firebaseRef);

$scope.messages.$add( 
  {
    FirstName: patient.FirstName, 
    LastName: patient.LastName
  }
).then(function(firebaseRef) {
  var id = firebaseRef.key();
});
```

The data is stored fine and I can see it on my dashboard. However, id is always a cryptic firebase value. I would love to be able to set it myself to something meaningful. In my case the individual patient's ID would be meaningful...

Any thoughts?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the response.

I found that the child function will do what I need. I first specify the child and then set it.

```
var patient_child = firebaseScreenRef.child(patient.PatientId); 
      patient_child.set(
        { 
            FirstName: patient.FirstName, 
            LastName: patient.LastName, 
        });
```

Comment: This helped! I first tried to use both $firebaseObject and $firebaseArray, but only ref worked - you have to use ref directly...

Comment: Took me some time to understand that, but it works. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Adding an item to a firebase array make firebase define a unique id for you. If this is not what you want, I think you can try getting the "messages" object with $firebaseObject, instead of getting just the list with $firebaseArray. Then you will be able to edit your object in js, in order to add your items to the messages collection. In this way you can use the id that best suits your needs. Finally, you have to $save() your entire object. Look here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebaseobject

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For your question, I found an explanation. You don't need to use firebaseObject, you should use ref directly:

```
var ref = new Firebase(FURL);

createProfile: function(id ,user) {

  var profile = {`enter code here`
                name: user.name,
                email: user.email,
                gravatar: get_gravatar(user.email, 40)
            };

  var profileRef = $firebaseArray(ref.child('profile').child(id));

  return ref.child('profile').child(id).set(profile);
},
```

In the code, I use ref to reference my URL. With profileRef, I created a child profile and I added id for the profile. Afterwards, I use ref directly to set the value `profile` for the id that I want. You see, it is very easy.